# How to handle null in a list with Rxjava2?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, rx-java2, reactive

I have a list of values and I going to print every element of it with Rxjava2 flowable. If there is null value, then, the program will print "it's empty value".

```
val datas: MutableList<String?> = arrayListOf("123",null ,"test12", "teas")

Flowable
            .fromIterable(datas)
            .subscribe(
                object: FlowableSubscriber<String>{
                    override fun onComplete() {
                        println("on complete")
                    }

                    override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
                        println("on subscribe")
                    }

                    override fun onNext(t: String?) {
                        if(t==null){
                          println("it's empty value")
                        } else {
                          println("value: $t")
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
                        println("error")
                        t?.printStackTrace()
                    }

                }
            )


        while(true){}
```

And I got the exception as below:

```
on subscribe
error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Iterator.next() returned a null value
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$IteratorConditionalSubscription.fastPath(FlowableFromIterable.java:311)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$BaseRangeSubscription.request(FlowableFromIterable.java:122)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.request(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:153)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMapMaybe$FlatMapMaybeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMapMaybe.java:107)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:67)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14827)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter.subscribeActual(FlowableFilter.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14827)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMapMaybe.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMapMaybe.java:54)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14827)
    at TestPlay.test4(TestPlay.kt:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I'm new in reactive rxjava, and I need some expert to guide me how to handle this scenario.

I have a scenario that I need to check with database if the record is not exist then I have to save the record. But when I try deal with null value, I got the exception as I described above.

Answer (score 4):

From RxJava2 documentation:

> RxJava 2.x no longer accepts null values and the following will yield
>   NullPointerException immediately or as a signal to downstream.

Solution: Before iterating list, you should make null check.

Answer (score 1):

How said [@Toleubek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7528364/toleubek) before: RxJava doesn't support null-values, 'cause they immediately terminate your stream and call onError(...) in your Subscriber.

You can read about it [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls). But the mostly using solution for dealing with nulls is simple creating some wrapper-class that will be called Optional/Nullable(or something like that) with the nullable data inside. Also you can read [one of the articles](https://medium.com/@joshfein/handling-null-in-rxjava-2-0-10abd72afa0b) about working with null in RxJava on Medium.